# Persistent store migration on iPhone 5s crashes tableview

Tags: ios, iphone, 64-bit, ios-simulator, core-data-migration

I have a relatively straightforward master detail application in Xcode 6.0.1 with iOS Simulator 8.0.

The application uses core data. The application is local only. I plan to use iCloud or Dropbox to backup
the data, but not for synchronization. At the moment it is local only.

Everything works beautifully with one huge exception. Every time I use the simulator and simulate iPhone 5s,
as soon as I migrate the store and then access the tableview detail, the app crashes. No log info, no error info,
it simply stops. Same is true for a 5s phone.

If I run the simulator in iPhone 5 mode, or run the app on an iPhone 4s it works perfectly. I've read dozens of
tutorials and articles about core data and the persistent store - never even heard of this issue.

So there must be some issue for post- persistent-store migration on the 64 bit devices. Can anyone help?

- (void)migrateStore:(NSString *)newSQLFileName {

  // migrate current store from one URL to another
  // write out the current store URL before the migration
  NSURL *storeURL = [self.persistentStoreCoordinator.persistentStores.lastObject URL];
  NSLog(@"storeURL before migration: %@", [storeURL description]);

  // get the current store
  NSPersistentStore *currentStore = self.persistentStoreCoordinator.persistentStores.lastObject;

  // create a new URL
  NSURL *newStoreURL = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] URLByAppendingPathComponent:newSQLFileName];

  //add the options dictionary once you get it working

  // migrate current store to new URL
  [self.persistentStoreCoordinator migratePersistentStore:currentStore toURL:newStoreURL options:nil withType:NSSQLiteStoreType error:nil];

  // check to see if the new store is active, write out the URL again
  storeURL = [self.persistentStoreCoordinator.persistentStores.lastObject URL];
  NSLog(@"storeURL after migration: %@", [storeURL description]);

}//migrateStore:newSQLFileName

from the debug log window:

2014-10-02 16:35:09.274 BiopLog[31758:2509702] User entered PIN to validate
2014-10-02 16:35:09.277 BiopLog[31758:2509702] ** User Authenticated!!
2014-10-02 16:35:09.389 BiopLog[31758:2509702] the document path is: /Users/john_grauel/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/25BCE099-41D2-4679-9A40-615656159E84/data/Containers/Data/Application/39A5A3FF-CBDE-42A0-B6BA-DBC632EE0E31/Documents
2014-10-02 16:35:12.384 BiopLog[31758:2509702] storeURL before migration: file:///Users/john_grauel/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/25BCE099-41D2-4679-9A40-615656159E84/data/Containers/Data/Application/39A5A3FF-CBDE-42A0-B6BA-DBC632EE0E31/Documents/BiopLog.sqlite
2014-10-02 16:35:12.843 BiopLog[31758:2509702] storeURL after migration: file:///Users/john_grauel/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/25BCE099-41D2-4679-9A40-615656159E84/data/Containers/Data/Application/39A5A3FF-CBDE-42A0-B6BA-DBC632EE0E31/Documents/BiopBak201410021635.sqlite
(lldb)

and the Devices log includes:

Oct  2 17:42:41 JohniPhone SpringBoard[48] : Application 'UIKitApplication:com.carbonrose.BiopLog[0x9dbb]' crashed.
Oct  2 17:42:41 JohniPhone assertiond[58] : pid_suspend failed for : Unknown error: -1, Unknown error: -1
Oct  2 17:42:41 JohniPhone assertiond[58] : Could not set priority of  to 2, priority: No such process
Oct  2 17:42:41 JohniPhone assertiond[58] : Could not set priority of  to 4096, priority: No such process
Oct  2 17:42:41 JohniPhone UserEventAgent[17] : id=com.carbonrose.BiopLog pid=886, state=0
Oct  2 17:42:41 JohniPhone locationd[55] : Location icon should now be in state 'Active'
Oct  2 17:42:41 JohniPhone geod[127] : Can't get bundle identifier for process 565
Oct  2 17:42:43 JohniPhone locationd[55] : Gesture EnabledForTopCLient: 1, EnabledInDaemonSettings: 0
Oct  2 17:42:43 JohniPhone kernel[0] : xpcproxy[888] Container: /private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/EC6B60D8-510D-4E46-82B1-29891D0F4E79 (sandbox)
Oct  2 17:42:43 JohniPhone yweather[888] : assertion failed: 12A405: libxpc.dylib + 71820 [4BC9CA3D-4DEE-314C-ADBF-53BDCEEFE45C]: 0x7d
Oct  2 17:42:43 JohniPhone Unknown[888] : 
Oct  2 17:42:43 JohniPhone yweather[888] : CFURLSetResourcePropertyForKey failed because it was passed this URL which has no scheme: /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/EC6B60D8-510D-4E46-82B1-29891D0F4E79/Documents/YI13N/sqlite/yi13nevents.db
Oct  2 17:42:43 JohniPhone yweather[888] : Enabling Crittercism v4.3.4...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had created an sqlite file with sample data and loaded that file when initializing the app. the difference in the storage of numbers from the 32 bit to the 64 bit machines was the reason the process was failing. The solution is to read in data from code and if later necessary, migrate the core data store to another device. the migration process will create the correct number storage locations.